# function_score query in elasticsearch won't change score

Tags: elasticsearch, solr-boost

I have an index with following doc structure: Company > Jobs (nested)

Company have name and jobs have address. I search jobs by address by default. Along with this, I'm trying to boost certain companies by their name using `function_score` query. But my query doesn't seem to be boosting anything or change scores.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {},
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "active_jobs",
              "score_mode": "max",
              "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "United States",
                  "type": "cross_fields",
                  "fields": [
                    "active_jobs.address.city",
                    "active_jobs.address.country",
                    "active_jobs.address.state"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "inner_hits": {
                "size": 1000
              }
            }
          },
          "functions": [
            {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "name": "Amazon"
                }
              },
              "weight": 100
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 30,
  "from": 0
}
```

[Update 1]
Here is the mapping for `active_jobs` property:

```
    "active_jobs": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "active": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "address": {
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state_code": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "dateOptionalTime"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to specify weight in the **functions**

Comment: Sorry, I did actually apply weight, but nothing changed. I missed it in the question, will edit it.

Without weight, the query is not valid, after I apply weight, i get the results but score are not changed at all.

Comment: What's the mapping for `active_jobs` field?

Comment: @AndreiStefan it is this:

    "address": {
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        },
       
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }

Comment: That's for `address` field only. What about the whole field definition?

Comment: You have `"path": "active_jobs"` so I know that `active_jobs` is at least a `nested` field.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Let me update the doc with the mapping

Comment: Yep, that is a nested property. Have updated the question.

Comment: just a guess  could it be possible **name** field is being analyzed ? In that case it should be **amazon** in lowercase in the terms filter of function score.

Comment: @keety has a good point. To test this, take out that `term` filter out of the main query and run it just by itself. See if it matches the documents you think it should.

Comment: @keety that was the problem! Thank you so much.